# How to avoid tab key on key down event using java script

Tags: javascript, .net, telerik

i need to block the tab key on user edit.

I am using vs2010 and rad editor.
i want to block the user to press tab key with in the editor to edit the content.

so, i am using the below code

```
if(e.keycode==9)
{ return false;}
```

it return false value, but the tab is working in dispaly.
i need to get this in IE9.

How to prevent the tab key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use jQuery, this answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6140696/551093

Answer (score 1):

Should you change `keycode` to `keyCode`?