# allowing tab key when we are allowing only numbers in textbox using java script

Tags: javascript, regex

i written a java script which allows only numbers,comma,dot. i applied it on four text boxes. my issue is i have 10 text boxes which takes different types of data on which four of them i applied java script. i can use tab key on other text boxes but i am not able to use on java script applied text boxes to move courser. is there any change that i have to do in my script... Thanks.

Java Script:-

```
function isNumberCommaDot(evt) {
         var theEvent = evt || window.event;
         var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
         key = String.fromCharCode(key);
         if (key.length == 0) return;
         var regex = /^[0-9,\9\b]*\.?[0-9]*$/;
         if (!regex.test(key)) {
             theEvent.returnValue = false;
             if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
         }
     }
```

i used \9 in regex but still its not accepting tab key.(9 is ASCII char. for TAB Key)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check whether it was a tab press earlier, and just skip processing

```
function isNumberCommaDot(evt) {
     var theEvent = evt || window.event;
     var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

     if (key === 9 ) { //TAB was pressed
        return;
     }

     key = String.fromCharCode(key);
     if (key.length == 0) return;
     var regex = /^[0-9,\9\b]*\.?[0-9]*$/;
     if (!regex.test(key)) {
         theEvent.returnValue = false;
         if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
     }
 }
```

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140632/how-to-handle-tab-in-textarea)