# How do I get the tab button to work in textareas in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page that has a textarea. I want to be able to use the tab button inside it instead of it switching focus. I included the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6140696/1953537) answer to another question, but the tab still switches focus. If I run that same code in my JavaScript console, however, it changes the behavior of the tab button to create a tab character.

The relevant code I tried is this:

```js
$("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) { // tab was pressed
    // get caret position/selection
    var start = this.selectionStart;
    var end = this.selectionEnd;

    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();

    // set textarea value to: text before caret + tab + text after caret
    $this.val(value.substring(0, start) + "\t" + value.substring(end));

    // put caret at right position again (add one for the tab)
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

    // prevent the focus lose
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="20" cols="150"></textarea>
```

Comment: Code works for me in Chrome. Change the \t to 4 spaces if that's what you need

Comment: is code shown run before element exists?

Comment: Yeah do remember to wrap the event handler in `$(function() {...});`