# Disable tab in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make an editor for my webpage so I can easily edit my pages. I'm using a `textarea` for the editor. The `textarea` is inside of a form.

Therefore, if I use tab to indent, the cursor jumps to the Submit button.

I found some methods to set the tabindex to -1, but this won't help.

Is there some way to disable the tab function?

```
<form method='GET' action='pages/save.php'>
 <textarea id='textbox' class='form-control' name='textarea' rows='20' cols='80'></textarea><br />
  <input id='safebutton' type='submit' value='Save' />
 </form>
```

Comment: Add listener for key press. If it is `tab` - do something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle <tab> in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140632/how-to-handle-tab-in-textarea)

Comment: This question is what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637341/use-tab-to-indent-in-textarea

Comment: You can do it using jqurey:
$(document).keydown(function (e) 
{
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

Comment: @MichaelHIrschler I have already tried that. I will try it again. Maby i made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to through this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hckck96/7/)

You will get which you want.

HTML :

```
<textarea placeholder='Enter text Here....'>

</textarea>
```

css :

```
textarea{

height:250px;
  width:100%;
}
```

JS :

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e) {


 if(e.keyCode === 9) { 
        var start = this.selectionStart;
            end = this.selectionEnd;

        var $this = $(this);

        $this.val($this.val().substring(0, start)
                    + "\t"
                    + $this.val().substring(end));

        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your Welcome @Bolphgolph.